# NuxtJS & WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack, nuxt.js, vue.js

Существует вопрос, *каким образом можно реализовать совместимость WordPress и NuxtJS*? Может быть *статейки* какие-то или *видео на youtube*? Может у кого-то есть опыт реализации подобной авантюры?

Comment: https://medium.com/@moustachedesign/creating-a-website-with-nuxt-js-and-wordpress-rest-api-51cf66599cf3

Comment: Думаю тут вы найдёте, то что ищете... [NuePress](https://github.com/krestaino/nuepress)